# Yes button on user administrator missing and cmd shows system error 5 has occured

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, administrator

I have 2 biggest problem here and i can't found it on youtube and here.

First i can't find the button "yes" on dialog box and it shows "To continue, enter an admin user name and password."
[See me](https://ibb.co/LgFJpvt)

Then, i found the video to fix this on here:
https://youtu.be/_gYejNAAmHU

But when i tried to follow the instructions instead of typing `net user administration /active:yes`, i got a typo on it and typed it as `net user administration /activated:yes`. Then, anything i typed on cmd it showed `system error 5 has occured`.

I can't do anything. Even if i tried to follow the instructions for repairing `system error 5 has occured`, it still needs "yes" button. But again, my problem is, the "yes" button is missing.
[See me](https://ibb.co/bJV3CgM)

Please help me. Tomorrow i have a presentation and i need to install a software. But without "yes" button, i can't install anything. Hope you can help me. It's urgent.
:(

Comment: Log out of your current user, see if the admin account shows up, if so log into that.

Comment: @Moab thanks for the asnwer, but I'm not in the sign in condition. Anf I've been trying to log in just now. But the "yes" button is still missing. Please help.

Comment: @user516076 click on "show more details" in that dialog box; and enter your admin account password; if still not clear attach an image of that too ; run this in cmd and edit your question to add the output :     net user